# How to use logic to control what is selected in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have the following query

```
select
  rel.firstobjectuuid,
  rel.secondobjectuuid
from
  Component$ comp
  inner join Relationship$ rel on comp.objectuuid = rel.firstobjectuuid or comp.objectuuid = rel.secondobjectuuid
where
  comp.componentid = '181814'
```

Does anyone know how I could tell this to select firstobjectuuid when comp.objectuuid=rel.secondobjectuuid. 

And select rel.secondobjectuuid only when comp.objectuuid=rel.firstobjectuuid?

So basically, I only want it to return either firstobjectuuid or secondobjectuuid. Which one is determined by the opposite of the one that was used for the inner join between Relationship$ and Component$

Edit:
I created a fiddle to help explain my awful explanation.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f655/1

(oracle doesn't seem to be working for sqlfiddle, so I had to make it mysql)

But I hope it helps explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Perhaps sample data and desired results would help convey what you want to do.

Comment: I added a fiddle. I tried your answer out put it wasn't returning what I wanted. It may be the opposite of what I want? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working with decode, which I had never heard about until now.

```
select
  decode(comp.objectuuid, rel.firstobjectuuid, rel.secondobjectuuid
                        , rel.secondobjectuuid, rel.firstobjectuuid) as final_value
from
  Component$ comp
  inner join Relationship$ rel on comp.objectuuid = rel.firstobjectuuid or comp.objectuuid = rel.secondobjectuuid
where
  comp.componentid = '181814'
```

EDIT: And I found an even better way of doing it that is database agnostic.

```
select
    case comp.objectuuid
        when rel.firstobjectuuid then rel.secondobjectuuid
        when rel.secondobjectuuid then rel.firstobjectuuid
    end
from
    Component$ comp
    inner join Relationship$ rel on comp.objectuuid = rel.firstobjectuuid or comp.objectuuid = rel.secondobjectuuid
where
    comp.componentid = '181917'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `left join` twice to bring in the matches on the different fields.  Then `coalesce()` in the `select` chooses the particular object id.

```
select coalesce(rel1.firstobjectuuid, rel2.secondobjectuuid)
from Component$ comp left join
     Relationship$ rel1
     on comp.objectuuid = rel.firstobjectuuid  left join
     RelationshipType$ reltype1
     on reltype1.relationshiptypeid = rel1.typeid and
        reltype1.uuid = 'RelType:Application_Disposition_provides-is_provided_by_Business_Function_UUID' left join
     Relationship$ rel2 
     on comp.objectuuid = rel.secondobjectuuid left join
     RelationshipType$ reltype2
     on reltype2.relationshiptypeid = rel2.typeid and
        reltype2.uuid = 'RelType:Application_Disposition_provides-is_provided_by_Business_Function_UUID'
where comp.componentid = '181814' and
      (reltype1.uuid is not null or reltype2.uuid is not null);
```

EDIT:

It is a little hard to understand the logic.  Perhaps the arguments to `coalesce()` should be the other way around?

```
select coalesce(rel2.secondobjectuuid, rel1.firstobjectuuid)
```

That way, if the second object matches, use it.  Otherwise use the first object.